# Django: is it possible to make the statement displayed with red color when we use a form crispy?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

Hi i want if a user forgot to fill out any field from the form , the phrase ""

This field is required. "" displayed with red color and not with black color , is it possible if yes! , How i can do that please or is there another way to do that!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caqI9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Find out what css class(es) are being attached to the error text and then supply CSS to cause it to display the way you want.  If there isn't an appropriate css class, you can add one with Crispy css_class arguments.

Browser right-click on an error text and "inspect object" should tell you the first part.

It seems to happen automagically for me, using Bootstrap and Crispy bootstrap Layout. However, the above answer is quite independent of Bootstrap.